# Dropshipping - Should I set up a business for this?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, small-business, business

I've been looking in to the world of dropshipping and am keen to give it a go myself.

I'm just curious if it would be wiser for myself to set up a business in order to do this or am I able to do it through personal means (i.e. through my personal bank accounts etc.)

If anyone could shed some light on this, that would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you use a credit card account with your personal name? It seems like a lot of trouble to register a business just to get things delivered to you.

Comment: I don't know if this is the right SE site for this. But you should at least check if you'd need to make the business official in your country. In mine (NL) I need a company to sell legally. But you can most likely use your own bank accounts until you decide you need one for business. Just check if the customer won't see data you don't want out in the open when they buy from you.

Comment: Just to double check, have you read the “scams” section here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop_shipping ? If you’ve done your own research and are happy, that’s fine, but I thought it was worth mentioning potentially for others who might see this question.

Comment: @Lawrence, I don’t think the Op is trying to get stuff delivered direct to him/her self but to set up as a drop shipper.

Comment: @MartijnVissers is there a SE you would recommend for this type of question? i'm happy to remove this and post elsewhere if need be

Comment: @Vicky you're right, i wouldn't be wanting the stock delivered to me directly. I also appreciate the link you provided regarding "scams", thanks!

Comment: I think in the UK i am able to set up shopify and whatever else via personal channels. But then would that make it more complicated in the future if i was making enough that a business should be started? In that case, should i just start the whole process by setting up a business? Sorry i'm quite clueless about these initial steps (just trying not to make any silly mistakes!)

Comment: @Wool Law.SE for the legal side of things, maybe economics.SE for the economical side of things. But I honestly don't know. Since it hasn't been closed forbeing off topic I assume it might be fine here.

Comment: I'd focus on what value you believe you'll add to the purchasing equation for a customer. With the proliferation of affiliate programs, if you're just another website from which to buy things there may not be much/any profit to be had as a drop-shipper.

Comment: @Vicky My mistake.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a company, and use your own bank account, then you are personally liable for any losses.
If something goes missing in the post, you have to refund the customer.

Worse, if one of your products injures a customer, and they are looking for someone to sue, then that's going to be you.  You are the importer and the retailer.